# maven - unable to find resource

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

everytime i run a maven build on a project i'm running, i get this:

```
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.org//org/jboss/aop/jboss-aop/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jboss-aop-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:pom:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT' in repository restlet (http://maven.restlet.org/)
Downloading: http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/aop/jboss-aop/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jboss-aop-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:pom:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT' in repository jboss-snapshots (http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.org//org/jboss/javaee/jboss-jca-api/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/jboss-jca-api-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jboss.javaee:jboss-jca-api:pom:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT' in repository restlet (http://maven.restlet.org/)
Downloading: http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/javaee/jboss-jca-api/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/jboss-jca-api-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jboss.javaee:jboss-jca-api:pom:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT' in repository jboss-snapshots (http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2)
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. The package you would like to use is not there. Try to find another repository or maybe your artifact was renamed. I found `jboss-aop` in `http://repository.jboss.org/` repository.